# Android ListView with style like iPhone Grouped UITableView

Tags: android, iphone, uitableview, listview

I have an iphone application that uses a UITableView. This table view uses the "Grouped" style and it looks quite good. Now i'm porting this application to android. Is there any Library/Example on how to make android's ListView look like iPhone's grouped UITableView  (rounded corners etc) ?

Answer (score 7):

Though, Personally, I wont recommend views with both platforms with their own sdk style, but if you still want to implement such a component. There is a Project hosted on GitHub, download the same and try with this.:

https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview